# How to resolve "Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data: could not convert string to float" error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv_data = '''A,B,C,D
... 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0
... 5.0,6.0,,8.0
... 10.0,11.0,12.0,'''
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))
df
imr= SimpleImputer(missing_values='np.nan', strategy='mean')
imr = imr.fit(df)
```

This code is meant to fill in any data that is considered NaN with the average numbers around it, the code is from a textbook I am using but the sklearn code in it was outdated so I tried implementing sklearn.impute

Here is the error I was given

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-56effb5bd123> in <module>
     10 df
     11 imr= SimpleImputer(missing_values='np.nan', strategy='mean')
---> 12 imr = imr.fit(df)
     13 imputed_data = imr.transform(df.values)
     14 imputeded_data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute\_base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    286         self : SimpleImputer
    287         """
--> 288         X = self._validate_input(X, in_fit=True)
    289 
    290         # default fill_value is 0 for numerical input and "missing_value"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute\_base.py in _validate_input(self, X, in_fit)
    258                 new_ve = ValueError("Cannot use {} strategy with non-numeric "
    259                                     "data:\n{}".format(self.strategy, ve))
--> 260                 raise new_ve from None
    261             else:
    262                 raise ve

ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: '... 1.0'
```